# clearTimeout(var) not clearing var timeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

**Project -->** http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/YpLgBX

**Description -->** I want to clear a timeout on this function when checkbox is not checked anymore.

```
  var holder2 = setTimeout(function() { 
  $("#matrix2").css('display','block'); },26570);
```

When you click matrix, little frog should start dancing after 26 seconds, problem is, if you cancel matrix mode and click submit (in 22th second lets say) and then really quick enable matrix mode again, the frog will start dancing after 4 seconds not 26, because timeout was still running.

**Problem ->** This is not working:

```
clearTimeout(holder2);
```

Also tried:

```
holder2.clearTimeout();
```

**Whole code**

```
$("#Confirm").on('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('matrixcheckbox').checked) {
        matrixreset();
        $("#unmute").show();
        $("#matrix2").css('visibility', 'visible');
        player.playVideo();

        var holder = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix1").css('display', 'block');
        }, 1900);
        var holder2 = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix2").css('display', 'block');
        }, 26570);

        $("#pi").css('background-image', 'url(' + 'http://i1007.photobucket.com/albums/af198/GoDHanD/My%20FS%20Profile/RedMatrix.gif' + ')');
    } else {
        matrixreset();
        clearTimeout(holder);
        clearTimeout(holder2);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is probably a scope problem, show the whole code so we can see what scope `holder2` is in

Comment: `clearTimeout(holder2);` is the right way. Either `holder2` is not accessible where you are trying to call it, or you assigned a new value in the meantime. Please read [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the whole code and the codepen link.

Comment: Do you guys know what i can do?

Comment: Remove `var` keyword from holder and holder2.

Comment: "I'm not going to waste 30 seconds of my time waiting for a frog to dance" is a sentence I never thought I'd have to write... Read the link offered by @FelixKling; remove any code that has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: nvm its just a scope issue. correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scope issue.  Every time this callback function is executed it will:

1. immediately create new undefined variables for `holder` and `holder2` ([because `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)).
2. enter the conditions

   a. *either* assign values to those new variables

   b. *or* run `clearTimeout` on the undefined variables.

At no point are the variables defined and getting cleared.

A solution would be to declare your timeoutID variable outside of the callback, so it persists between calls (first line):

```
var holder, holder2;

$("#Confirm").on('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('matrixcheckbox').checked) {
        matrixreset();
        $("#unmute").show();
        $("#matrix2").css('visibility', 'visible');
        player.playVideo();

        holder = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix1").css('display', 'block');
        }, 1900);
        holder2 = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix2").css('display', 'block');
        }, 26570);

        $("#pi").css('background-image', 'url(' + 'http://i1007.photobucket.com/albums/af198/GoDHanD/My%20FS%20Profile/RedMatrix.gif' + ')');
    } else {
        matrixreset();
        clearTimeout(holder);
        clearTimeout(holder2);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, the thing is i also tried this but i had var next to the function variables aswell, so it would just create a new variable.  ;))

Answer (score 2):

It is a scope issue, define variable outside the click handler like following

```
var holder,holder2;

$("#Confirm").on('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('matrixcheckbox').checked) {
        matrixreset();
        $("#unmute").show();
        $("#matrix2").css('visibility', 'visible');
        player.playVideo();

        holder = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix1").css('display', 'block');
        }, 1900);
        holder2 = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#matrix2").css('display', 'block');
        }, 26570);

        $("#pi").css('background-image', 'url(' + 'http://i1007.photobucket.com/albums/af198/GoDHanD/My%20FS%20Profile/RedMatrix.gif' + ')');
    } else {
        matrixreset();
        clearTimeout(holder);
        clearTimeout(holder2);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, the thing is i also tried this but i had var next to the function variables aswell, so it would just create a new variable.  ;))